# How can I add an entry to database with one of the columns titled 'release'?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a record to mySQL database, when I do so I get the following message:

sqlMessage: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'release) values ( \'/ge-assets/images/bottoms-webinar.png\', \'Sign Up Now!\', \'2018\' at line 1',

When I try to add it exactly the same without the 'release' column everything works fine - I am able to append the entry. So I understand something is wrong with the 'release' title, however searching around it doesn't seem like a reserved keyword (I looked in w3schools, and around SO).

```
query = `insert into ${CURRENT_DB_TABLE} (image_path, button_text, release) values ( '${entry.image_path}', '${entry.button_text}', '${entry.release}')`;

return mysqlConnection.query(query).then((response) 
    console.log("appended entry :: ",entry.title);
```

I cannot add it without the column names (because one of my columns has to remain empty).

Comment: `release` is definitely a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-R). You need to enclose it in backticks `\`` to use it  as a column name in a query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: "doesn't seem like a reserved keyword (I looked in w3schools, and around SO)" - the first search should really be official docs :) Things change, keywords get added...

Comment: Thanks for that. Something still doesn't work, I think it has to do with the fact that the whole expression is already in backticks. Or to the fact that backticks have a meaning in JS as well.

Comment: JavaScript template string can contain backslash-escaped backticks. However, that's another issue: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com). Do not use template strings to fill in values into SQL expressions; use prepared statements instead. ````query = `INSERT INTO ${CURRENT_DB_TABLE} (\`image_path\`, \`button_text\`, \`release\`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`; mysqlConnection.query(query, [entry.image_path, entry.button_text, entry.release]):````